# Can't access my user account Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, home-directory

I have no idea why but it just sends me back to the login screen whenever I try to login my main account. So I made a second account from guest account and used nautilus as sudo(root) and checked my home main user files and all that is there is:

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt
```

But I don't understand I haven't encrypted my drive so what do I do to get my data back, I would really like to get it back I can't understand what has happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice but I've fixed it now. Those files didn't exist in the users home directory.

I created a new account and coppied all the files I needed. Then deleted the old user account.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same situation when I was using 11.10. Here is how I solved it:

- At log in screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
- login with your username/password
- `ls -Shla | grep “Xauthority”`
- `sudo mv .Xauthority Xauthority.old`
- `sudo shutdown -r now`

[Source](http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/10/how-to-solve-unable-to-login-into-ubuntu-11-10/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. `cd` to your home directory and delete the `.Xauthority` & `.ICEauthority` files in your home directory and then try to login.

*p.s : Try to check your Display manager too*